# Download and install informatica for integrating it with hadoop

Tags: hadoop, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I am trying to work on a POC for integrating Informatica with Hadoop. I have already completed my study and gathered lot of useful information. Now I am planning to implement it on my personal laptop. What I need is informatica 9.5.1 version or above for integrating with hadoop as it has the new features in Power Exchnage which has the capability to connect to HDFS.

Can someone please guide me for installing Informatia on my laptop (Not sure what all components should be downloaded like Informatica Server, DB etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Informatica provides a pre-configured trail version VM with all the required connectors configured for hadoop, the same can be downloaded from the below site, but the minimum ask of 10GB RAM

https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/bdecloudera

Answer (score 0):

System Requirements:
Atleast 1GB of system memory is needed.

Following softwares are needed to install Informatica:
1) Database, for eg: Oracle 12C, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2

2) For installing informatica, Oracle Business Intelligence Data Warehouse Administration Console 11g and Informatica PowerCenter and Power Center Adapters 9.61
This can be found at the below link:
https://edelivery.oracle.com
and search for "Oracle Business Intelligence Data Warehouse Administration Console"

These files contain both server and client setups. You will have to install them both. Once these two components are installed, Informatica loads the system with Powercenter Designer, Workflow Manager, Repository Manager etc

Comment: Thank you so much Dex. I will try this option and keep you posted on the same.